# Create a generator that returns every permutation (unique arrangement) of positive integers up to n

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, interview-questions, reinventing-the-wheel

I watched [this video from The Unqualified Engineer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7hHupttzVk) on YouTube and tried out the challenge. The challenge (or interview question) is to build a generator that returns all the permutations of the positive integers up to \$n\$ (that is, \$1,2,3,\ldots,n\$).

I know about [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) but want to implement it myself.

```
def gen_perm(n):
    l=tuple(range(1,n+1))
    yield l
    while True:
        l=increment_lex(l)
        if(not l):
            raise StopIteration
            break
        yield l

def increment_lex(l):
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        x=len(l)-(i+1)
        y=len(l)-(i+2)
        if l[x] > l[y]:
            m=min([i for i in l[x:] if i > l[y]])
            cl=list(l[x:])
            cl[cl.index(m)] = l[y]
            il=tuple(l[:y] + (m,) + tuple(cl[::-1]))
            return il
    return

for i in gen_perm(3):
    print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```

In order to extend this to the other direction as well, however I couldn't think of a way to do it without adding two additional functions:

```
def gen_perm_reverse(n):
    l=tuple(range(n,0,-1))
    yield l
    while True:
        l=decrement_lex(l)
        if not l:
            raise StopIteration
            break
        yield l

def decrement_lex(l):
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        x=len(l)-(i+1)
        y=len(l)-(i+2)
        if l[x] < l[y]:
            m=max([i for i in l[x:] if i < l[y]])
            cl=list(l[x:])
            cl[cl.index(m)] = l[y]
            il=tuple(l[:y] + (m,) + tuple(cl[::-1]))
            return il
    return
```

Apologies for the use of `l` as an identifier. It works nicely on my editor font but not here.

Comment: What was wrong with `list(itertools.permutations(range(1, n+1), n))` and using `reverse` for the other way around? Is it a [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] question?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger it's no fun that way

Comment: Take a look at the [Python code for `itertools.permutations`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l2534).

Answer (score 4):

## Style

Readability is impaired because you don't use the space bar enough. Put a space around `=` for assignments, after `,`, around binary operators. Parenthesis are also not required in `if` statements.

You also use 1-letter variable names which doesn't convey any meaning, which makes it harder to understand the code.

## Duplicated work

`gen_perm` and `gen_perm_reverse` are basically the same function with some minor tweaks: the `range` and the "increment" function to call. Increments functions are the same too, only the comparison (`<` vs `>` and `min` vs `max`) change.

You can merge the two of them and parametrize it with a `reverse` parameter that default to `False`.

```
import operator

def permutations(n, reverse=False):
    numbers = range(1, n+1)
    permutation = tuple(reversed(numbers) if reverse else numbers)

    yield permutation
    while True:
        permutation = next_permutation(permutation, reverse)
        if not permutation:
            return
        yield permutation

def next_permutation(permutation, reverse=False):
    compare = operator.lt if reverse else operator.gt
    top = max if reverse else min

    max_length = len(permutation) - 1
    for i in range(max_length):
        x = max_length - i
        permutable = permutation[x - 1]
        if compare(permutation[x], permutable):
            m = top(i for i in permutation[x:] if compare(i, permutable))
            cl = list(permutation[x:])
            cl[cl.index(m)] = permutable
            return permutation[:x-1] + (m,) + tuple(cl[::-1])
```

A couple of changes here:

- Instead of raising `StopIteration`, you can just `return` from a generator. In any case, having a `break` after a `raise` is poor practice since it is unreachable code.
- I computed `len(permutation)` (`len(l)`) less time in `next_permutation` and assigned `l[y]` to a variable to reduce the cost of retrieving it.
- I removed the call to `tuple` when creating the object to be returned since it already it a tuple.
- The last `return` was also unnecessary as it is implicit anyway.

The drawback of this approach is that you now perform much more comparisons to `reverse` to be able to get the right comparison functions. You can get rid of it either by passing the functions as parameters or by combining both functions:

```
import operator

def permutations(n, reverse=False):
    numbers = range(1, n+1)
    compare = operator.lt if reverse else operator.gt
    top = max if reverse else min
    permutation = tuple(reversed(numbers) if reverse else numbers)
    max_length = n - 1

    yield permutation
    while True:
        for i in range(max_length):
            x = max_length - i
            permutable = permutation[x - 1]
            if compare(permutation[x], permutable):
                m = top(i for i in permutation[x:] if compare(i, permutable))
                cl = list(permutation[x:])
                cl[cl.index(m)] = permutable
                permutation = permutation[:x-1] + (m,) + tuple(cl[::-1])
                break
        else:
            # We didn't break -> no more permutations available
            return
        yield permutation
```

Here I used the [`for .. else`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct to detect when we couldn't produce an new permutation and stop the generation accordingly.

## Building on my comment

As I said in a comment, the most straighforward way to achieve that in python is by using [`itertools.permutation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
import itertools

def permutations(n):
    return itertools.permutations(range(1, n+1))
```

the advantage, beside its simplicity of use, is that the reverse version is straighforward too:

```
def permutations(n, reverse=False):
    numbers = range(1, n+1)
    return itertools.permutations(reversed(numbers) if reverse else numbers)
```

But being able to use both the forward and reverse iteration had me thinking about defining a class:

```
import itertools

class Permutations:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.numbers = range(1, n+1)

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.permutations(self.numbers)

    def __reverse__(self):
        return itertools.permutations(reversed(self.numbers))
```

Usage being:

```
perm_3 = Permutations(3)
for i in perm_3:
    print(i)
for i in reversed(perm_3):
    print(i)
```

The advantage here is that, if you really don't wan't to use `itertools`, you can plug in your custom function easily:

```
import operator

class Permutations:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.numbers = range(1, n+1)

    @staticmethod
    def _permutation_helper(permutation, compare, top):
        max_length = len(permutation) - 1

        yield permutation
        while True:
            for i in range(max_length):
                x = max_length - i
                permutable = permutation[x - 1]
                if compare(permutation[x], permutable):
                    m = top(i for i in permutation[x:] if compare(i, permutable))
                    cl = list(permutation[x:])
                    cl[cl.index(m)] = permutable
                    permutation = permutation[:x-1] + (m,) + tuple(cl[::-1])
                    break
            else:
                # We didn't break -> no more permutations available
                return
            yield permutation

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._permutation_helper(tuple(self.numbers), operator.gt, min)

    def __reverse__(self):
        return self._permutation_helper(tuple(reversed(self.numbers)), operator.lt, max)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I have learned a lot. Do you have any feedback on whether it's possible to avoid list indexing in this generator? Perhaps with some clever list slices and zips? I'm under the impression that it's better to avoid `for in range(len(x))` altogether.